# Map reduce code for group by with having clause and where conditions

Tags: php, mongodb, dictionary, reduce

I have a users collection as following

```
{
    "id":"id here", 
    name: 'name here', 
    height: 'height here', 
    weight: 'weight here', 
    lastLogin:[array of login dates], 
    messagesSentOn: [array of messages sent date]
}
```

I need to find all users who have logged in last month but more than once and who have sent more than 25 messages on the last month and whose weight is more than 50 and height is more than 5 inches. How do I write a map reduce function in mongodb for the above case?

Answer (score 1):

I've provided an example in the shell. I'm not sure that MR is the best solution for this problem, and I encourage you to consider alternate solutions to avoid single-threaded Javascript.  For example, you could store an additional field that only contains logins or messages of the current month. Each time you add logins and/or messages, you increment a counter field.  This schema would allow you to find matching documents without an aggregation command.

You should also look into the new aggregation framework, which will be available in MongoDB version 2.2 (coming out soon): http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

One final note- to improve performance, you should make sure to include a query in the MR command to weed out non-matching documents (see the example below).

input documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Jenna", "height" : 100, "weight" : 51, "lastLogin" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], "messageSentOn" : [ 4, 5, 5, 7 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Jim", "height" : 60, "weight" : 49, "lastLogin" : [ 2, 4 ], "messageSentOn" : [ 5, 6 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Jane", "height" : 90, "weight" : 60, "lastLogin" : [ 1 ], "messageSentOn" : [ 3, 6 ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "Joe", "height" : 70, "weight" : 65, "lastLogin" : [ 5, 6, 7 ], "messageSentOn" : [ 3, 6, 7 ] }
```

MR functions:

```
map = function(){ 
   var monthLogins = 0; 
   var monthMessages = 0; 
   var monthDate = 2;  
   for(var i=0; i<this.lastLogin.length; i++){     
       if(this.lastLogin[i] > monthDate){         
            monthLogins++; 
       } 
   } 
   for(var i=0; i<this.messageSentOn.length; i++){     
      if(this.messageSentOn[i] > monthDate){         
         monthMessages++; 
      } 
   } 
   if(monthLogins > 1 && monthMessages > 2)
      { emit(this._id, null); 
   } 
}

reduce = function (key, values) {
   //won't be called because a single document is emitted for each key
}
```

MR command:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(map, reduce, {query: {weight: {$gt : 50}, height: {$gt: 5}, lastLogin: {$gt: 2}}, out: {inline:1}})
```

Output:

```
{"_id" : 1, "value" : null},
{"_id" : 4, "value" : null}
```